# How to Redirect to a Certain Page When Given Certain Input

Tags: javascript, html, input, redirect

This is my second day coding, so forgive me if I don't know how to explain properly or if its a basic solve.

I'm trying to replicate a console interface on a website, and I want the input box to redirect to a certain link only if it's given a certain input. I would also like it to not redirect at all and give a message if its given an invalid prompt.
The code for the input box I have so far is

```
  <form action="backlog">
    <label for="fname">     
    <input type="text" name="logsarchives" id="logsarchives" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Enter Console Command">
    </form>
```

The code so far can be viewed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTOYTKHH3NV4) and the website can be viewed [here](https://whatsinthemirror.neocities.org/backlog.html).
Thank you for reading this!

Comment: is Pedro Sturmer's answer doesn't satisfy you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'd need a little JavaScript to handle this case. Also there is just unnecessary amount of tags been used without a proper closing purpose or even a closing tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="logsarchives" id="logsarchives" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Enter Console Command" onkeydown="redirect(this)">
    </body>
    <script>
        function redirect(ele) {
            if(event.key === 'Enter') {
                if(ele.value === 'google')
                     window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
                else
                    alert("Invalid");
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a javascript function to submit your form, get the value of the input inside of it, and then check if it matches!

Html:

```
<form action="backlog" onsubmit="myFormSubmit()">
  <input type="text" id="logsarchives" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const myInput = document.getElementById('logsarchives');

  if (myInput.value == 'something') {
    window.location = 'http://google.com'
  }
}
```

You may want to remove the action attribute of your form, this makes your submission redirect automatically.
Also, only works when you submit the form (by pressing a button or enter on your keyboard) if you want it to work automatically you may be searching for onChange method of the input Element.

Here's a pen you can play around! :) https://codepen.io/pedrost/pen/RBLOgY

Answer (score 0):

Add javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("logsarchives").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    var valid-options = ["option1", "option2", "soforth"];
    var input = document.getElementById("logsarchives").value;
    for (var i = 0; i < valid-options.length, i++) {
        if(input === valid-options[i]) { /*or ==*/
            window.location.replace("/backlog?logsarcives=" + valid-options[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```